# Maven build for Munits - Mule

Tags: xml, spring, maven, munit

I am preparing maven for building mule application which contains munits. I am getting below error when i "mvn package" the application.

> WARN  2016-11-11 09:35:32,415 [main]
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader: Ignored
>   XML validation warning org.xml.sax.SAXParseException:
>   schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document
>   'http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws/current/mule-ws.xsd', because
>   1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3)
>   the root element of the document is not .     at
>   org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown
>   Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.8.0.jar:?]     at
>   org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.warning(Unknown Source)
>   ~[xercesImpl-2.8.0.jar:?]
>
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   com.mulesoft.munit.tools:munit-maven-plugin:1.2.1:test (test) on
>   project api-system-plm-material: Execution test of goal
>   com.mulesoft.munit.tools:munit-maven-plugin:1.2.1:test failed:
>   org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Line 19 in XML document
>   from URL
>   [file:/D:/Mule-Workspace-28thOct/myapplication/target/test-classes/myapplication_flow1.xml]
>   is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
>   lineNumber: 19; columnNumber: 105; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid
>   content was found starting with element 'ws:consumer-config'. One of
>   '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":annotations,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":description,
>   "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans,
>   "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean,
>   "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context":property-placeholder,
>   "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":ref,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":global-property,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":configuration,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":notifications,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-extension,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-shared-extension,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-extension,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-agent,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-security-manager,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-transaction-manager,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-shared-transaction-manager,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-connector,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-shared-connector,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-global-endpoint,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-exception-strategy,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-flow-construct,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":flow,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":sub-flow,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-model,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-interceptor-stack,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-filter,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-transformer,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":processor-chain,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":custom-processor,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-empty-processor,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":invoke,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":set-payload,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-global-intercepting-message-processor,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":custom-queue-store,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-processing-strategy}'
>   is expected. (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException) -> [Help
>   1] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal com.mulesoft.munit.tools:munit-maven-plugin:1.2.1:test
>   (test) on project api-system-plm-material: Execution test of goal
>   com.mulesoft.munit.tools:munit-maven-plugin:1.2.1:test failed:
>   org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Line 19 in XML document
>   from URL
>   [file:/D:/Mule-Workspace-28thOct/myapplication/target/test-classes/myapplication_flow1.xml]
>   is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
>   lineNumber: 19; columnNumber: 105; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid
>   content was found starting with element 'ws:consumer-config'. One of
>   '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":annotations,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":description,
>   "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans,
>   "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean,
>   "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context":property-placeholder,
>   "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":ref,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":global-property,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":configuration,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":notifications,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-extension,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-shared-extension,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-extension,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-agent,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-security-manager,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-transaction-manager,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-shared-transaction-manager,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-connector,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-shared-connector,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-global-endpoint,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-exception-strategy,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-flow-construct,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":flow,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":sub-flow,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-model,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-interceptor-stack,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-filter,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-transformer,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":processor-chain,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":custom-processor,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-empty-processor,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":invoke,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":set-payload,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-global-intercepting-message-processor,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":custom-queue-store,
>   "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-processing-strategy}'
>   is expected. (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)

The flow xml it is referring to is:

> http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
>   http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core
>   http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
>   http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws
>   http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws/current/mule-ws.xsd
>   http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw
>   http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd
>   http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http
>   http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd">
>
> ```
> <ws:consumer-config name="Web_Service_Consumer" service="Mat_RFCService" port="MAT_RFC" 
>   serviceAddress="${service.address}" 
>   wsdlLocation="MAT_WSDL.wsdl" doc:name="Web Service Consumer" connectorConfig="MAT-HTTP-Endpoint"/>
> ```

Below is my pom.xml:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
 <artifactId>myapplication</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>mule</packaging>
 <name>Mule myapplication Application</name>
 <properties>
     <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
     <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
     <mule.version>3.8.1</mule.version>
     <mule.tools.version>1.2</mule.tools.version>
     <munit.version>1.2.1</munit.version>
     <mule.munit.support.version>3.8.0</mule.munit.support.version>
     <!-- This is the domain where the app will be 
     deployed: i.e. mydomain.cloudhub.io -->
     <cloudhub.domain>mydomain</cloudhub.domain>
 </properties>
 <build>
     <plugins>
     <plugin>
       <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
       <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.1.1</version>
       <!-- <configuration>
             <deploymentType>standalone</deploymentType>
             <muleVersion>${mule.version}</muleVersion>
         </configuration> -->
         <configuration>
             <deploymentType>cloudhub</deploymentType>
             <muleVersion>3.8.2</muleVersion>
             <username>username</username>
             <password>mypassword</password>
              <applicationName>myapplication-maven-1.0</applicationName>
              <!-- <businessGroup>engineering\devops</businessGroup> -->
             <target>CloudHub</target>
             <!-- One of: server, serverGroup, cluster -->
             <domain>${cloudhub.domain}</domain>
             <targetType>server</targetType>
             <environment>DEVELOPMENT</environment>
         </configuration>
         <executions>
             <execution>
                 <id>deploy</id>
                 <phase>deploy</phase>
                 <goals>
                     <goal>deploy</goal>
                 </goals>
             </execution>
         </executions>
     </plugin>
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-app-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.tools.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <copyToAppsDirectory>true</copyToAppsDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-resource</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-resource</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/app/</directory>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>mappings/</directory>
                                </resource>
                            <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/api/</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-mule-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <excludeMuleDependencies>false</excludeMuleDependencies>
                    <inclusions>
                        <inclusion>
                            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mule-module-objectstore</artifactId>
                        </inclusion>
                    </inclusions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>munit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${munit.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <coverage>
                        <runCoverage>true</runCoverage>
                        <formats>
                            <format>html</format>
                        </formats>
                    </coverage>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/munit</directory>
            </testResource>
        <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
    </build>

    <!-- Mule Dependencies -->
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Xml configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-core-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Xml configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mule Transports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-file</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-http</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-jdbc-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-jms-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-vm</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mule Modules -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-scripting</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-xml</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- for testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.tests</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-tests-functional</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-apikit</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-munit-support</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.munit.support.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit</groupId>
            <artifactId>munit-runner</artifactId>
            <version>${munit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-objectstore</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mule.modules/mule-module-spring-extras -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-spring-extras</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
          <repository>
            <id>Central</id>
            <name>Central</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>mulesoft-release</id>
            <name>mulesoft release repository</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Any clues will be of great help.

Edit:

After adding dependency as indicated by Dds, i am now caught with the below error:
`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.mulesoft.munit.tools:munit-maven-plugin:1.2.1:test (test) on project myapplication: Execution test of goal com.mulesoft.munit.tools:munit-maven-plugin:1.2.1:test failed: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:myapplication-get-id.xml]
[ERROR] Offending resource: URL [file:/D:/RamG/Eclipses/Workspaces/Mule-Workspace-28thOct/myapplication/target/test-classes/myapplication-apikit-test.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [myapplication-get-id.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [com.mulesoft.weave.mule.config.WeaveNamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Option (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException): scala.Option
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]`

When i browsed for information, i see that one more SO question was posted but not answered. It is referring to dataweave + scala/Option which is same as the error i am getting.

For some reason this dataweave component does not get fully downloaded, particularly the jar file is not downloaded. After some exercise, i have downloaded and copied to the respective .m2 folder **manually**. But following that i see the above error. So, it either has some dependencies which are not resolved like 'scala/Option"!! I am not sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi there those kind of errors when running from Maven usually indicates a missing dependency in your pom file.

The one containing the web service consumer should be:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
  <artifactId>mule-module-ws</artifactId>
  <version>${mule.version}</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Please add that one to you pom and give it a try.
HTH

Comment: That's really helped me. I will mark as answered. The issue continued with another error: `[DEBUG] BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext`. Can you tell me what is this dependency or issue referring to? Thanks

Comment: That doesn't look like a missing dependency, but rather like an issue with the mule app/munit test config files.
I've not idea really with only that stack trace. I'll advice you to open another question and to try and scope out the issue. It could be that you're loading your app partially (in the spring import) and something may be missing